# Check for pattern and replace in words of sentence python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a sentence and for each word in the sentence check if the word has certain apostrophes is present or not and f they are present, replace them else continue. I have defined my apostrophes in a `dict`. The `key` of the dict has the pattern and `value` has the actual value which replaces the pattern. I tried the following code

```
tweet = "you're his i'm couldn't can't won't it's"
apostrophes = {"'s":" is","'re":" are","'ll":" will","'d":" would","i'm":"I am","I'm":"I am","won't":"will not", "'ve":" have","can't":"cannot","couldn't":"could not"}

words = tweet.split()

for word in words:
    for k in apostrophes.keys():
       if k in word:
           word = word.replace(k,apostrophes.get(k))
       else:
           pass
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, other than "it does not work"?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to escape a string for insertion into a database.  If that's anywhere even remotely close (not sure why else apostrophes are a concern) then this approach is _flawed_.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to split the words and to loop over them:

```
tweet = "you're his i'm couldn't can't won't it's"
apostrophes = {"'s":" is","'re":" are","'ll":" will","'d":" would","i'm":"I am","I'm":"I am","won't":"will not", "'ve":" have","can't":"cannot","couldn't":"could not"}

for k, v in apostrophes.iteritems():
    tweet = tweet.replace(k, v)

print tweet # you are his I am could not cannot will not it is
```

(Note that this is python 2.7)

Comment: This would be a problem if the values in the dictionary overlapped with the keys (like substrings of each other)

Comment: True. Although the same problem would have happened in the original code. It should work for this particular dict.